# Are there any tools for unit testing VodaPay Mini-Programs?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

What are, if any, the testing tools used for test automation when you develop mini-programs on the VodaPay Mini-Program platform? I'm looking specifically to do Unit and E2E testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mini program development platform does not support testing tools directly out of the box. Unit and Integration testing can be incorporated into the platform via a test suite such as Jest or Mocha.

Automated E2E Testing is unsupported since it requires you to run them in a headless browser, which you don't have access to since it compiles to a JavaScript bundle that can only be consumed by a super-app.

Answer (score 3):

As a tester for mini programs. I am currently trying out TestProject which seems to be working well. Still early on and haven't picked up any issues with it yet. Runs the expected journey on the mobile device as well as performing checks on validations messages and text comparisons as instructed during the test case.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Jest works quite well when writing unit tests for Vodapay mini-programs. You just need to add a file to mock the JSAPI calls, here is a sample of how I have done this in the past.

```
/* istanbul ignore file */
let page, app, component;
global.App = (obj) => {
  app = obj;
};
global.Page = (obj) => {
  page = {
    data: {},
    ...obj,
    setData(data) {
      this.data = { ...this.data, ...data };
    }
  };
};
global.Component = (obj) => {
  component = obj;
};

global.my = {

  alert: (obj) => {
    return obj;
  },
  request: (obj) => {
    return obj;
  },
  redirectTo: (obj) => {
    return obj;
  },
  navigateTo: (obj) => {
    return obj;
  // Do Nothing
  },
  setStorage: (obj) => {
    // Do Nothing
  },
  getStorageSync: (obj) => {
    // Do Nothing
  }
};

export { app, page, component };
```

You can use Jest's setup files to have this included before each of your test files.

In your test files, you can import the page, app, or component that you are testing and you will have access to the object that you use as an argument.